# CA common to two servers under load balancer

Tags: ssl, openssl

I would like to set up a TLS authentication on the two-server setup with a load balancer that spreads traffic between them. I do not have access to the load balancer, so I need to set up both servers separately. I need a certificate that would be signed by my own CA that I can pass on to the client which I want to authenticate. I know that it is possible to create a CA that is common for both servers, I am not sure how though. Is it as simple as creating a CA on each server with the same configuration?

I would appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS uses TCP connections, so the load balancer will only balance the establishment of TCP connections. After that the client is tied to any one of the two servers.

The certificate the servers present to their clients should match the URL or IP of the load balancer, so the clients can check if the certificate matches what they intended to connect to.

If you expose which backend server the client has reach (eg. because the load balancer redirects the connection, instead of tunneling it), your servers will probably need a wildcard certificate.

Comment: I think I was not clear enough in my questions. If I understand your answer right, you are talking about the server certificate. However, I am thinking about a client certificate authentication. I have my CA and I generated a client certificate, which I will be verifying and client's request will end up in one of the servers (choice is up to the load balancer).

Comment: I don't think the verification of the client certificate is any different when using a load-banalcer compared to a standalone server.

Comment: well, the problem is that the verification can't happen on the load balancer. so the same client certificate should be accepted by both servers.

Comment: Each server needs a copy of the public key of your CA to verify the client certificate, just like your web browser can verify a certificate from a public CA eg. a SSL web server, based on it's public key.

Comment: I managed to get it to work right before your comment;) Works just fine as you explained. Thanks!